# How can I add user to role in this script? Discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have script in JS which checks first:

1. if user has been given/taken a role
2. next if given role have id = 728446135441817702
3. then have to add user to next role with id = 728422773558607926

My script:

```
client.on("guildMemberUpdate", function (oldMember, newMember) {          //1 part
 if (newMember.roles.cache.has('728446135441817702')) {                   //2nd part
  //3rd part; here add user to next role (i try but i dont know how to do this in this case) 
}})
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
client.on("guildMemberUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if (newMember.roles.cache.has("728446135441817702")) {
        newMember.roles.add("728422773558607926");
    };
});
```

Comment: But i have one more question...
Its possible to check if user have rank on server #1 and if yes then add rank on server #2?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: I try to do this with yours code. 2nd part was role from #1 server and 3rd part was role from #2 server and i get error

Comment: "(node:29487) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not an Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes."
Any idea?

Comment: You passed in an invalid parameter. It should be a Role object, Snowflake (which is the ID of the role, as a String), or an array/collection of Role objects / Snowflakes.

Comment: Its my code:



client.on("guildMemberUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if (newMember.roles.cache.has("728446135441817702")) {
        newMember.roles.add("737289046317072419");
    };
});

Comment: imo everything is ok but i got error. First id is from #1 server and second id from #2 server

Comment: You're trying to add the role from Server 2 in Server 1. You'll have to get the Server 2 as a Guild object, get the member you are trying to add a role too, and then add the role.

Comment: Ok. Can you maybe help me with that because I'm not sure how to do it?

Comment: I've created an [example](https://hastebin.com/tuloyedoco.cs) for you.

Comment: Okay. I will try to understand it and next use it in my bot :). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read the [Discord.JS Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) - most stuff is covered in there.

The code I believe you require is:

```
newMember.roles.add('ID');
```

If this doesn't work, please do leave a comment and I will change the code within this answer - although it should work. Please do consider accepting this as the answer and/or upvoting if this has helped you.

**FROM COMMENT:**

```
client.on("guildMemberUpdate", function (oldMember, newMember) {
  if(newMember.guild.id === "GUILD_ID_1"){
    var guildMember = client.guilds.cache.get("GUILD_ID_2").members.cache.get(newMember.id)
    guildMember.roles.add("ROLE_ID")
  }
)}
```

As usual there could be a small mistake in that code, if so please do leave a comment below and I will correct it.

Comment: But i have one more question... Its possible to check if user have rank on server #1 and if yes then add rank on server #2?

Comment: Yep. Please view the BOTTOM code block above, I have included that code there.